# Regex match text with provided start and end

Tags: regex

I have a string (srcset data) and I need to match only the url starting with `/images` and ending with `t2-q5.jpg`

Input data:

```
       /images/upload/test/test/test/name-t2-q1.jpg  576w, 
            /images/upload/test/test/test/name-t2-q2.jpg  864w, 
      /images/upload/test/druckprodukte/flyer/name-t2-q3.jpg 1151w, 
                      
           /images/upload/produkt/druckprodukte/flyer/name-t2-q4.jpg 1439w,                
      /images/upload/produkt/druckprodukte/flyer/name-t2-q5.jpg 1725w
```

The formatting with multiple space characters is accurate as this is what I get when selecting the element from DOM.
Any input on how to construct the regex?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Beside the escaping of special characters, there is no difficulties.

Just search for (possibly with the global flag) :

```
\/images\/.*t2-q5\.jpg
```

Playground :
https://regex101.com/r/JCnmkO/1

Comment: Issue is that in the code snippet  there are newline characters and then your regex works. I have no newline characters, just space and if that is the case it matches everything.